# Why is $\sqrt{ (\frac{(x^2+1)}{2})^2-x^2}=|\frac{x^2-1}{2}|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Background: This was a simplifying step in a longer equation from a problem calculating the electrostatic potential.

Why would $\sqrt{x^4+1^2}$ be the distance of x^2 from 1? For instance x=1 would yield $\sqrt{2}$ and not $0$.

Comment: The distance from $x^2$ to $1$ is just $|x^2-1|$,  unless I'm misunderstanding your question. And it is not equal to $\sqrt{x^4 + 1^2}$.

Comment: That's why I'm confused. Let me add the entire step in case the answer to the simplification wasn't an incorrect use of absolute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|$. Hence, it suffices to show that
$$
\frac{(x^2+1)^2-4x^2}{4}=\frac{(x^2-1)^2}{4},
$$
which is easy.

Comment: I forgot to square the two in the denominator when reading it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2}\right)^2-x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{4}-\frac{4x^2}{4}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^4-2x^2+1}{4}}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x^2-1}{2}\right)^2}=\left|\frac{x^2-1}{2}\right|$